# Creating Windows Authentication for Single controller in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created the Web Api in ASp.net core. I need to add Windows authentication for the Particular controller. I tried using web config file using Handler. But its not working.

Comment: Can't see your web.config file. Set the authentication mode  to Windows. Also, you need make necessary settings in IIS. Please refer- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: The above link helps only for IIS 7. But i am working in IIS 10. It will not work .

Comment: <location path="api/controller"><authorization><system.web><deny users="?" /></authorization></system.web></location>

Comment: By not working, what do you mean exactly? What is happening precisely when you call your Web Api method?